# How to show the legend of Rechart graph in docx

Tags: reactjs, docx, recharts

I would like to embed a Recharts graph into a word document generated within React. The graph is correctly embedded after clicking the button but its legend is not correct.

The image is created as follows;

```
              <LineChart {...chartProps}>
                <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />

                <XAxis dataKey="name" />
                <YAxis />
                <Legend />
                <Line
                  isAnimationActive={false}
                  type="monotone"
                  dataKey="pv"
                  stroke="#8884d8"
                  activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
                />
                <Line
                  isAnimationActive={false}
                  type="monotone"
                  dataKey="uv"
                  stroke="#82ca9d"
                />
              </LineChart>
```

Then the svg is changed into blob;

```
        // Render the chart component to an SVG markup
        const svgMarkup = renderToString(chartComponent);

        // Convert the SVG markup to a Blob
        const blob = new Blob([svgMarkup], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
```

The chart embeded into docx is as follows;

[image]

The code in codesandbox.io is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-fermat-1hokry) Click the button and obtain the word document.